# Abnormal records

Tags: r, data.table

I have this data.table A:

```
Person  characteristics1
     A                 1
     A                 1
     A                 2
     A                 1
     A                 1
     A                 1
```

One can see there is abnormal record in "characteristics1" which is 2. How do I write a function to tell that since most of the records in "characteristics1" column is 1, I want to change the "2" to "1"?

Many thanks

Comment: We can check how far the value is from the mean?

Comment: How do you really know what value is "abnormal"? That doesn't look that unusual to me (then again I have no idea what characteristics1 actually represents". You're going to have to be a bit more specific about exactly what values you want to change. Maybe provide a more robust example with input and desired output for that input that shows both columns/rows you want to change and those that you don't.

Comment: The characteristics1 is constant over time so it should have 1 all the time. The "abnormal" entry may due to a small error in data collection.

Comment: What happens if it is `1,1,1,2,2,2` ?

Comment: Or what if there are only two values for A: 1,2. How do you decide which is right?

Comment: The data is from a survey and that entry may come from a typo if that make sense? For example the person is male (1) and he will always be male (1). The (2) may be a typo from the guy who enter the data. Forget about transgender... haha

Comment: We are not questioning the data, but how would you decide which one is the correct one, when there is a tie? `1,2` or `1,1,1,2,2,2` ?

Comment: The majority of the data is 1, the typo may only comes like one in a hundred of records...

Comment: Then go with the majority, the most frequent one is the correct one, and hope there are not ties :) ... also, some might find it offensive the `"Forget about transgender... haha"`

Comment: Sorry about that, I take it back!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your looking for the mode. R doesn't have a built-in function for mode, but you can create a function to do that:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- unique(v)
  uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}

df[,characteristics1:=getmode(characteristics1), by=Person]

   Person characteristics1
1:      A                1
2:      A                1
3:      A                1
4:      A                1
5:      A                1
6:      A                1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know how correct your way of thinking is but you can look for the most repeated value and update the column based on that with:

```
df$characteristics1=names(which.max(table(df$characteristics1)))
```

Wrap the part to the right of the `=` with `as.numeric()` if you only work with numbers.